# MVC4 Model's binded property lost after submitting POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

The problem that I have encountered is that although the AssignedUsers property is initialized in my constructor (before leaving the GET Edit), it arrives back as a null in the POST Edit action, after submitting the form. All the other properties keep their state.

Is there any other way to get past this, besides re-initializing the property after the ModelState.IsValid check (and before returning the View)?

**Model:**

```
 public class GroupModel {

    public List<int> AssignedUserIds { get; set; }

    public MultiSelectList AssignedUsers { get; set; }

    public GroupModel(Groups group) {
        var allUserGroups = AccountManagementAdapter.GetUserGroups();

        AssignedUsers = new MultiSelectList(
            allUserGroups
            .Where(userGroup => userGroup.GroupId == Id)
            .Select(userGroup => userGroup.Users)
            .ToList(),
            "Id",
            "Username");

        AssignedUserIds = allUserGroups
             .Where(userGroup => userGroup.GroupId == Id)
             .Select(userGroup => userGroup.UserId)
             .ToList();
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ListBoxFor(group => group.AssignedUserIds, Model.AssignedUsers)
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
        GroupModel groupModel = new GroupModel(AccountManagementAdapter.GetGroups().FirstOrDefault(group => group.Id == id));
        return View(groupModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(GroupModel group) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            group = new GroupModel(AccountManagementAdapter.UpdateUsersForGroup(group.Id, group.AssignedUserIds));
            ViewBag.Success = true;
        }

        return View(group);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not posting the data in your form. So it's not going to be returned back to the edit method. Which is the way you should do it, I wouldn't recommend posting the data to your form.

I would make a change like this

Model:

```
 public class GroupModel {

    public List<int> AssignedUserIds { get; set; }

    MultiSelectList _assignedUsers;
    public MultiSelectList AssignedUsers () {
       return _assignedUsers ?? _assignedUsers = new MultiSelectList(
            AllUserGroups
            .Where(userGroup => userGroup.GroupId == Id)
            .Select(userGroup => userGroup.Users)
            .ToList(),
            "Id",
            "Username");
    }
    private object _allUserGroups; /* not sure what this is */
    private object AllUserGroups {
          get { return _allUserGroups ?? _allUserGroups = AccountManagementAdapter.GetUserGroups();
    }

    public GroupModel(Groups group) {
           AssignedUserIds = AllUserGroups
                 .Where(userGroup => userGroup.GroupId == Id)
                 .Select(userGroup => userGroup.UserId)
                 .ToList();
   }
```

View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(group => group.AssignedUserIds, Model.AssignedUsers())
```

**OR** you could do this

```
public class GroupModel {

    public List<int> AssignedUserIds { get; set; }

    public MultiSelectList AssignedUsers { get; set; }

    private object allUserGroups
    public GroupModel() {
        allUserGroups = AccountManagementAdapter.GetUserGroups();
        AssignedUsers = new MultiSelectList(
            allUserGroups
            .Where(userGroup => userGroup.GroupId == Id)
            .Select(userGroup => userGroup.Users)
            .ToList(),
            "Id",
            "Username");
    }
    public GroupModel(Groups group) :this() {
        AssignedUserIds = allUserGroups
             .Where(userGroup => userGroup.GroupId == Id)
             .Select(userGroup => userGroup.UserId)
             .ToList();
    }
```